# D-Bus, UDisks and Glibmm's bindings

Tags: linux, glib, dbus, variant

I'm having a problem with a simple D-Bus concept. I'm using Glibmm D-Bus bindings (Gio::DBus namespace) to access the UDisks interface. I'd like to read some attributes of every hard disk found on the system, so first I need to enumerate all disks that UDisks is reporting, like this:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gio::DBus::Connection> bus;

int main() {
    using namespace Glib;
    using namespace Gio;

    Glib::init();
    Gio::init();

    bus = DBus::Connection::get_sync(Gio::DBus::BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM);
    RefPtr<DBus::Proxy> udisks_proxy = DBus::Proxy::create_sync(bus, "org.freedesktop.UDisks", "/org/freedesktop/UDisks", "org.freedesktop.UDisks");

    VariantContainerBase devices_variant = udisks_proxy->call_sync("EnumerateDevices");
    VariantIter iterator(devices_variant.get_child(0));

    Variant<ustring> var;
    while(iterator.next_value(var)) {
        ustring name = var.get();

        LOG("device: '%s", name.c_str());
        process_device(name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work OK, because `call_sync()` returns a `VariantContainerBase`, which holds the `(ao)` object, which basically is: "one struct of an array of object paths". From the docs I read that the "object path" type is handled in the same way as a "string" type, that's why the untyped `VariantBase` that is created during `get_child(0)` allows itself to be casted into `Variant<ustring>` object. Using this parametrized Variant, it's trivial to extract the string by using `var.get()`.

But then I'm trying to read some stuff (in this case, the `NativePath` attribute) from the attributes of each drive using this method:

```
void process_device(const Glib::ustring& objpath) {
    using namespace Glib;
    using namespace Gio;

    RefPtr<DBus::Proxy> attrs = DBus::Proxy::create_sync(bus, "org.freedesktop.UDisks", objpath, "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties");

    std::vector<VariantBase> args;
    args.push_back(Variant<ustring>::create(objpath));
    args.push_back(Variant<ustring>::create("NativePath"));
    VariantContainerBase data = attrs->call_sync("Get", VariantContainerBase::create_tuple(args));

    LOG("return type: %s", data.get_type_string().c_str());
}
```

The problem is that the `VariantContainerBase` object contains the `(v)` signature. This means that the object is "variant", so I can't cast it to anything.

Introspection of the attributes show that `NativePath` holds a **string** value. So why the `call_sync()` method is returning an object of a variant type? Am I missing something? Could anyone tell me, how can I properly read the `NativePath` attribute, without using `get_data()` method and without `memcpy`'ing the data into my own buffer? I'd like to do it as type-safe as possible.

One more thing. When I use the `data.print(true)` method, I get the proper contents of `NativePath` attribute in an encoded form. This means that the engine knows that this is a **string**. So why it reports it as a variant? Is it a bug or a feature? :P

Sorry for my english, my confusion, and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have the solution: this seems to be a bug, or at least it's a logic that I don't understand.

Instead of calling `VariantContainerBase`'s `get_child(0)`, a proper way is to call a direct Glib function `g_variant_get_child()`, like f.e. this:

```
GVariant *output;
g_variant_get_child(data.gobj(), 0, "v", & output);
```

It will properly set the `output`'s variant type to one that's inside `v` (in my case it will set the type of `output` to `s`). After this, when you get the remote data in the `s` type, you can cast it to a `Variant<ustring>` like this:

```
Variant<Glib::ustring> item(output);
Glib::ustring text = item.get();
```

It seems to work.